# Azure AD is not redirecting to the MDM term of use URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, mdm

I have added an MDM (On-Premise) to Azure AD tenant in order to auto-enroll users (on windows 10) to a third party MDM once they sign in with their Azure AD accounts. When users try to sign in on Access work or school >> Connect >> Join this device to Azure Active Directory they got this error: **Something went wrong. Looks like we can't connect to the URL for your organization's MDM terms of use**.

Checking the MDM's server logs I realize that Azure AD never calls/redirect the user to the MDM's terms of use URL, in other words, on the MDM server there is no sign that Azure AD is trying to reach it.

Would you please give me some hints why this happens?.

On Azure AD tenant I have configured the following:

1. Enabled P2 license for each user.
2. Scope of the MDM is set to *Some* and for a Group where its members need to be enrolled to the third party MDM.
3. On MDM Settings (on Azure AD) the reply URL (just one) is set correctly.
4. MDM terms of use URL and discovery are set correctly.

   The MDM config on Azure AD looks like this:
   [Azure AD MDM URL configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBRIh.png).
   The MDM Properties on Azure AD look like this:
   [Azure AD MDM properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1xZI.png).

In advance thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD Premium P2 license allows you to join Azure AD with the Windows client, but it does not include Intune.

I would check settings to see if you auto-enroll is configured for Intune. That could explain the above message.

Also, please ensure that you have the right App ID URI and App ID configured as setting the wrong one here can also cause this error.

Comment: Thanks it helped me,however, I found that the MDM terms of use URL I used wasn't a FQDN, i.e. in the form of https://fabrikam.contosomdm.com/TermsOfUse. My bad, but why MS requires FQDN anyways?.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today from an OOBE and all of my searching pointed to licensing issues, which turned out to not be the fix for me.

The object in Azure AD had been disabled.  This was strange because it was an autopilot device and was disabled in AAD straight from the vendor, which hadn't been the case for other devices I had been receiving for years.  I searched for and enabled the device in AAD and it joined without issue.  I poked around and found about 30 other devices were in the same state.  Hopefully this isn't a new step I'll have to do for all autopilot devices going forward.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).